# How to make responsive image in carasoul while the images are in different sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I’m having some trouble with the images in one of my pages. They are in a carousel, but as the carousel slides to the next image, it is constantly changing sizes because the images are different sizes. I have tried to set them all to be the same size, but it doesn’t seem to matter, they are still different sizes. What do I need to do to make it so they are the same size so the carousel will remain consistent through each slide?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)

So, you can ignore the JavaScript and HTML in the snippet below.

In CSS what I've done is given a fixed `width` of `150px` to all my images and a `1:1` `aspect-ratio` (because I know all my images are square).

*Comment out the `aspect-ratio` code and you can see the difference.*

```js
let
  currImg = 0,
  totalImgs = 4;

const
  container = document.getElementById("container"),
  leftBtn = document.getElementById("left-btn"),
  rightBtn = document.getElementById("right-btn"),
  nav = (delta) => {
    container.children[currImg].classList.remove("show")
    currImg = (currImg + totalImgs + delta) % totalImgs
    container.children[currImg].classList.add("show")
  },
  navLeft = () => nav(-1),
  navRight = () => nav(1)

leftBtn.addEventListener("click", navLeft)
rightBtn.addEventListener("click", navRight)
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" class="show" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/500" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/600" />
</div>
<button id="left-btn">Left</button>
<button id="right-btn">Right</button>
```

Comment: Is    it     possible to   solve the problem only the use of css

Comment: @SudipBhattarai Ya it is only using CSS. The Javascript part is to only make a demo carousel.

Comment: @SudipBhattarai Please let me know if your issue is fixed or you need some help.

Comment: @SudipBhattarai Glad that I could help. Consider accepting this as an answer if it solved your problem.